# Android studio: this project is not gradle based project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have one project which was initially in eclipse, then i managed somehow to convert it to gradle and everything was working fine in Android Studio.

But then i didn't work some time with the project and after few months when i returned to project i am surprised that Android Studio has problems with this project.

When i selected "Android" from top left dropdown in AS, where you should see the project as Android, i saw no files, then i did something and now i see there one empty folder Java.

If i hit button "sync project with gradle files" AS says message as posted in name of question, but it is gradle based project.. there are gradle files etc.

Do you someone know why is this problem? Why it should stop work like this?

Thank you

Comment: make sure you opened the project from its root directory (one that contains the top level build.gradle file)

Comment: hi AndroidMechanic, thank you for your answer, you want post it as answer? it worked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you open the project from its root directory. i.e. the directory which contains the top level `build.gradle` file.

The missing top level gradle file is what causes this error.

Comment: yes it worked thanks. i had project with subfolder sources where was the sources, but i was opening the root folder (which was in recent projects of android studio) then it is strange, that in recent folders was not the sources subfolder! anyways.. it worked..

Answer (score 4):

## For native Flutter Projects:

Note that this error will also appear if you "sync your project with Gradle files " in the root directory. **Gradle works only in your android directory** (`flutter_name/android`).

#### Configure Gradle version

I got this error because i wanted to change some build values like the Gradle version and the Gradle plugin version (and other build values ex. kotlin):

1. In your current project: `File>Open`
2. Select directory: `user/StudioProjects/flutter_name/android`
3. Open directory in a new window
   After it is opened it will load some packages (see right bottom), which will take some time.
4. Under `File>Project` `Structure Project` you can set the gradle version and under `Modules` variables of your build
5. **Now you can sync your project with Gradle files** or at least read out the error messages, that come with your configuration

After configuration, you might need to restart your project with `File>Invalid Caches/Restart...`.

Comment: Upon removing the "proguard-rules.pro" file and cleaning the code. It worked for me

Comment: I mentioned your solution in my question. That solution didn't work for me but I think it's on the right path. Maybe you could help me to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/74209183/12695188

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me:

1. copy the file `build.gradle`
2. drop the copied file `build.gradle` in
   your app/project folder .

Answer (score 0):

My project stopped showing all of sudden and already had build.gradle file.
I just reopened it via File > Open.