# How do you share code from Android Studio into GitHub without it losing it's gradle and functionality when teammate clones it?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, github, version-control, clone

[Properly working project not from GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEOXO.png). My team and I are trying to use version control for Android Studio via GitHub. The code is operating fine on my computer and then I upload it to GitHub creating a repository. The problem comes in (I think) when my teammates clone the code to their Android Studio environment. When they open the code on their Android Studio they can't use "preview" for seeing the layout of the app. There also is no APP file structure for them as there is for me when I view the APP I originally created. There is also an error message saying "This project 'some project' is not Gradle based" we're completely befuddled as it seems as if it should be a simple transfer of files. Any idea on what we're doing wrong.

Broken and cloned project from GitHub

[image]

Comment: Did you change the default `.gitingore` files in Android Studio? If yes, [edit] the question and post it here. When you open the project in Android Studio for the first time, it takes little time to build. Hence, you're not getting preview properly. Change your project structure view from `Project` to `Android` on the left-hand side. Check this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39826294/5180017) once.

Comment: And your both the screenshots are the same I can't see any differences in it.

Comment: yeah I posted the wrong picture by accident!! SMH

Comment: We didn't do anything with .gitignore, we don't know anything about that. I tried changing Project to Android, but it's not even an option It's just not even an option in the drop down. I've let the project sit till this morning and the preview mode still says "loading" and there still is no android option.

Comment: Check the answer link I mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: How do I choose where to open the application from? I thought the root folder is the root folder and unless you do some manual restructuring it stays that way.