# Flutter project is not a Gradle-based (Android Studio)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

### My issue

My IDE raises the above event log:

[image]

### Research

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68665087/12695188), which suggests configuring the Gradle version from the `Structure Project` as the following:

[image]
[image]

I have set everything right and even created a dummy flutter project and compared the two structures. Nothing seems to be wrong.

On the other hand, my project Gradle preferences raises a `gradle-wrapper.properties` not found error while the new dummy project does not:

[image]

Honestly, I don't know if it's related to the `Project Sync` issue.

### My configuration

flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.1, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-x64, locale en-IL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.70.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

./gradlew --version

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-02-08 09:58:38 UTC
Revision:     f0d9291c04b90b59445041eaa75b2ee744162586

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          1.8.0_341 (Oracle Corporation 25.341-b10)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.0 x86_64
```

Good to note that the `JVM` version is 1.8 while I configured version 11 (maybe because of the sync failure).

**What can cause the `Sync Project` error? How to fix that? And what are it's consequences?**

Comment: Try to open android-app subdirectory from you flutter project in IDE.

Comment: I did exactly that in my "Research" paragraph. I reached the Project Structure by opening the android-app on a separate IDE window.